# Prove the equality for the function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

could you help me with the problem?
Let $f:R \to R $ is differentiable on $R$.
Prove that exists $x \in [0;1] $ such that:
$$(\frac4\pi)((f(1)-f(0) = (1+x^2)f'(x)$$

I tried to use mean value theorem:
$$f(1)-f(x) = f'(x)(1-x);$$
and 
$$f(x)-f(0) = f'(x)(x);$$

after that I tried to sum it, but it didn't give anything.

Comment: Note that the mean value theorem only tells you that $f(1)-f(x) = f'(c_1)(1-x)$ for some $c_1\in (x, 1)$. Similarly $f(x)-f(0) = f'(c_2)x$ for some $c_2\in(0, x)$. After summing up we would get $f(1)-f(0) = f'(c_1)(1-x)+f'(c_2)x$ for some $0<c_2<x<c_1<1$.

Answer (score 4):

Taking $g(x) = \arctan(x)$, from [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem) we obtain for some $c\in(0, 1)$:
$$\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \frac{f(1)-f(0)}{g(1)-g(0)} \implies f'(c)(1+c^2) = \frac{4}{\pi}\left(f(1)-f(0)\right) $$

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

Use the mean value theorem on $x \mapsto \tan^{-1}(x)$ and  on $f$. And multiply the two inequalities you get.